# Why is this recursive function never ending if the base case is reached?

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

So I'm trying to follow this Ullmann's algorithm for solving the subgraph isomorphism problem, by impementing it on Python. It says to stop the algorith when a compatible matrix is found, but my code keeps on printing the rest of the matrixes found, even when it reaches the base case. What am I doing wrong?

```
recurse(used_columns, cur_row, G, P, M)
    if cur_row = num_rows(M)
        if  M is an isomorphism:
            output yes and end the algorithm

    for all unused columns c
        set column c in M' to 1 and other columns to 0
        mark c as used
        recurse(used_column, cur_row+1, G, P, M')
        mark c as unused

    output no
```

This is how I coded it:

```
def permute(m0,row,h,g):
    if(row==len(m0)-1):
        n=0
        for i in range(len(m0[0])):
            for j in range(len(m0)):
                n+=m0[j][i]
            if(n>1):
                return
            n=0
        res=[[sum(a*b for a,b in zip(m0_row,h_col)) for h_col in zip(*h)] for m0_row in m0]
        resTr=[[res[j][i] for j in range(len(res))] for i in range(len(res[0]))]
        arr=[[sum(a*b for a,b in zip(m0_row,resTr_col)) for resTr_col in zip(*resTr)] for m0_row in m0]
        for row in arr:
            print(row)
        if(g==arr):
            print("YES!")
            return
    for n in range(len(m0[0])):
        m0[row][n]=0
    for n in range(len(m0[0])):
        m0[row][n]=1 #mark c as used
        permute(m0,row+1,h,g)      
        m0[row][n]=0 #mark c as unused
    print("No")
    return
```

This is the output:

```
[0, 0, 1]

[0, 0, 1]

[1, 1, 0]

YES!

[0, 0, 1]

[0, 0, 1]

[1, 1, 0]

YES!

No

No

[0, 0, 1]

[0, 0, 1]

[1, 1, 0]

YES!

[0, 0, 1]

[0, 0, 1]

[1, 1, 0]

YES!

No

[0, 0, 1]

[0, 0, 1]

[1, 1, 0]

YES!

[0, 0, 1]

[0, 0, 1]

[1, 1, 0]

YES!

No

No
```

I'd just like to print the first occurrence and actually stop, and print "No" when no identical matrix is found. Can anyone help?

Comment: So much for Python code being readable.

Comment: Instead of just `return` you should utilise the return value and check what it is. So you could `return true` on "Yes!", and `return false` otherwise. Then in your final for loop just do `if permute(...): return true`. Otherwise, how does it know to exit the loop immediately? I'm not 100% sure if this will get desired behaviour, can you give an example input and maybe I can make a complete answer?

Comment: It's printing "YES!" when called recursively.  It then returns, where the calling instance continues executing.  If you want it to do something different, you'll need to plan it out and make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any exit condition. Python doesn't care that you printed "YES!" so utilising return values becomes necessary. You should return `True` when the algorithm is finished, and `False` otherwise. Additionally, you must check for this value when the function calls itself (your final `for` loop) and pass along that `True` value, so it stops immediately:

```
def permute(m0,row,h,g):
    if(row==len(m0)-1):
        n=0
        for i in range(len(m0[0])):
            for j in range(len(m0)):
                n+=m0[j][i]
            if(n>1):
                return False
            n=0
        res=[[sum(a*b for a,b in zip(m0_row,h_col)) for h_col in zip(*h)] for m0_row in m0]
        resTr=[[res[j][i] for j in range(len(res))] for i in range(len(res[0]))]
        arr=[[sum(a*b for a,b in zip(m0_row,resTr_col)) for resTr_col in zip(*resTr)] for m0_row in m0]
        for row in arr:
            print(row)
        if(g==arr):
            print("YES!")
            return True
    for n in range(len(m0[0])):
        m0[row][n]=0
    for n in range(len(m0[0])):
        m0[row][n]=1 #mark c as used
        if permute(m0,row+1,h,g): #exit when finished
            return True     
        m0[row][n]=0 #mark c as unused
    print("No")
    return False
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to actually use an output later in your program; You could return that variable instead of `True`, pass the value down, and return `None` otherwise. The change would be minor, the new final `for` loop would become this:

```
for n in range(len(m0[0])):
    m0[row][n]=1 #mark c as used
    out=permute(m0,row+1,h,g)
    if out: #exit when finished
        return out
    m0[row][n]=0 #mark c as unused
```